# Pass string to Data frame - For loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code example. I basically want to parse the string inside the loop.

```
import pandas as pd
x =['C1','D1']
for name in Loco:
    df=df[df.x != 0  ]
    df=d [x].diff().abs()
```

What I need is for example, the two lines below to run

```
df=df[df.C1 != 0  ]
df=df['C1'].diff().abs()
df=df[df.D1 != 0  ]
df=df['D1'].diff().abs()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try with loc:

```
x =['C1','D1']
for name in x:
    df.loc[df[name]!= 0,name]=df.loc[df[name]!= 0,name].diff().abs()
```

sample dateframe:

```
from numpy.random import randint
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['C1']=randint(0,5,(10,))
df['D1']=randint(0,5,(10,))
```